# Hyper-V WMI: Import virtual machine and create snapshot

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v

I'm using the [Hyper-V WMI Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136992%28VS.85%29.aspx) to import virtual machines in Hyper-V, specifically using the [`ImportVirtualSystemEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379583%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method of the [`Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136940%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class, largely using the C# code snippets provided by MS.

I need to create a snapshot immediately after import, using the [`CreateVirtualSystemSnapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136785%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method, but I can't figure out **how to identify the newly imported virtual machine** among all the other virtual machines that have already been imported in Hyper-V.

I was hoping to get something back from the `ImportVirtualSystemEx` method, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised that the [`Msvm_VirtualSystemImportSettingData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379577%28VS.85%29.aspx) class that is created using the [`GetVirtualSystemImportSettingData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379581%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method during import contains all the information I need.